# Testforblock - Chest with a specific amount of items in it

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I tried to test for a chest containing 10 coal. When I tried this, it didn't work:

```
testforblock ~-1 ~ ~ minecraft:chest -1 {Items:[{Slot:0b,id:"minecraft:coal"}],Count:10b,Damage:0s}
```

It only works when I test for 1 coal, but then, I have to drop the `Count` and `Damage` tag. I want to test for 10 coal in a chest, not just for one.

Comment: You need to move `Count` and `Damage` to inside the item compound, the same place where `id` is. Note that it will only work in the top-left slot unless you remove `Slot:0b`.

Answer (score 1):

Use this command instead:

```
testforblock ~-1 ~ ~ minecraft:chest -1 {Items:[{Slot:0b,id:"minecraft:coal",Count:10b,Damage:0s}]}
```

This works because the `Count` and `Damage` keys must be between the same brackets (in the same object and the same array)  as the `id` key.

*Note*, if you want to test for the items in any of the inventory's slots, remove the `Slot` key.